# java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format Exception

Tags: windows, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3, trinidad

I have a JSF 2.0 (Trinidad) application using PRIMEFACES 3.3 SNAPSHOT component and i am trying to use the p:schedule but every time the page with the tag is called i get the exception. The weird part is that when i am using a normal JSF application without trinidad it works.

Here is the stacktrace:
`SEVERE: java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:137)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.CoreResponseStateManager._restoreSerializedView(CoreResponseStateManager.java:289)

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for my code. Just  wrap code in`<h:form></h:form>`